# Angular 7 - Unit test for an observable with subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, testing, angular7

Hi I am trying to write angular code for a component with an observable but I can't test the subscribe function. How Should I access the subscribe function? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**This is my component with the observable:**

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    if (this.authService.getUser() !== null || this.authService.getUser() !== undefined) {
      console.log('getUser');
      this.userService.userDetails = this.authService.getUser();
    }

    if (this.environmentName === 'QA' || this.environmentName === 'LOCAL' || this.environmentName === 'QA-STAGING') {
      console.log('environmentName');
      this.authService.acquireTokenSilent(['api://012fdc3a-c966-4312-9b5c-301f097c1803/server']);
    } else {
      this.authService.acquireTokenSilent(['api://58a80bb5-906b-4ec0-9b41-7a78a07125af/server']);
    }

    this.subscription.add(
      this.broadcastService.subscribe('msal:acquireTokenSuccess', (payload) => {
        // do something here
        console.log('acquire token success ' + JSON.stringify(payload));

        this.roleService.checkServerEventReviewers().subscribe(res => {
          this.userService.userDetails.role = res ? 'Data Steward' : 'Mosaic Consumer';
          if (this.isLoggedIn !== true) {
            const redirectUri = sessionStorage.getItem('redirectUri');
            if (redirectUri !== undefined || redirectUri !== null) {
              this.router.navigateByUrl(redirectUri);
            }
          }
          this.isLoggedIn = true;
};
```

**This is my spec file that I am trying:**

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    let subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      providers: [WindowService, RoleService, HttpClient, HttpHandler, BroadcastService, MsalService,
        {
          provide: MSAL_CONFIG,  // MsalService needs config, this provides it.
          useFactory: () => ({   // Note this is an arrow fn that returns the config object
            redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/',
            clientID: mockData.clientID,
          }),
        }],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  describe(':', () => {
    function setup() {
      const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
      const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
      return {fixture, app, compiled};
    }

    it('Init with QA environment', () => {
      const {app} = setup();
      spyOn(app.authService, 'getUser').and.returnValue(mockData.userDetails);
      spyOn(app.authService, 'acquireTokenSilent').and.returnValue('msal:acquireTokenSuccess');
      app.ngOnInit();
      app.subscription.add(
        app.broadcastService.subscribe('msal:acquireTokenSuccess', () => {
        // do something here
        });
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but more of an indirect one.  It might not be that great of an idea to have all this business logic in your component.  I would recommend using a library to assist with all your state management (we use [NgRX](https://ngrx.io/)).  A lot of this logic can then be moved into services or other pure methods that will be much easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

We should be creating mocks of our services whenever we create new angular service. 
Example Code:

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

export interface IUserService {
  getUser(): Observable<User>;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService implements IUserService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  getUser(): Observable<User> {
    return this.httpClient.get<User>('http://localhost:5000/api');
  }

}

@Injectable()
export class MockUserService implements IUserService {
  getUser(): Observable<User> {
    const user: User =  ...;
    return of(user);
  }

}
```

After creating mocks of services, in your actual component, assume you know nothing about what's going on in your component. What you should know is that you will be logged in on initialization(that's what I interpreted from your example code).

```js
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { HttpClientTestingModule } from "@angular/common/http/testing";
import { TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { By } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { RouterTestingModule } from "@angular/router/testing";
import { MsalModule } from "@azure/msal-angular";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { RoleService } from "./core/role.service";

describe("AppComponent", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        CommonModule,
        MsalModule.forRoot({
          clientID: "..."
        })
      ],
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: UserService,
          useClass: MockUserService
        },
        {
          provide: RoleService,
          useClass: MockRoleService
        }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it("Should create the app", () => {
    it("should create the app", () => {
      const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      const app = fixture.componentInstance;
      expect(app).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });

  it("Init with QA environment", async () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);

    // Don't use fixture.componentInstance in this method. You tests should be 
    // written in such a way that tests shouldn't fail when component code is 
    // refactored(method/property names are changed).
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;

    // Execute ngOnInit and other startup code
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // Wait for ngOnInit(and its subscriptions) to complete
    await fixture.whenStable();

    // check if particular UI is available in HTML after successful login
    /**
     * <div *ngIf="loggedIn">
     * <span class="hello">Hello</span>
     * </div>
     */
    const helloElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".hello"));
    expect(helloElement).toBeTruthy();
  });

 it("Role should be Data Steward", async () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);

    // Angular 9 has inject, in previous version, use TestBed.get(UserService)
    const userService = TestBed.inject(UserService);

    // Execute ngOnInit and other startup code
    fixture.detectChanges();
    // Wait for ngOnInit(and its subscriptions) to complete
    await fixture.whenStable();

    expect(userService.userDetails.role).toBe('Data Steward');
  });
});
```

Comment: I understand what you mean but I am trying to specifically test the role of the user and due to which I need to access the subscribe method in which the role is being determined. 
If you could suggest something. That would be helpful

Comment: Are you asking if you want to check user was navigated to `redirectUri`?

Comment: Either that or I would like to check the role according to this line `this.userService.userDetails.role = res ? 'Data Steward' : 'Mosaic Consumer';`

Comment: I edited the test code and added one more test case  `expect(userService.userDetails.role).toBe('Data Steward');`

Comment: Thank you for replying, I really appreciate it but I get this error 
**Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined**

Comment: Run `npm test`, Open F12 in the launched Google Chrome, Go to `Sources` tab, `Ctrl + P` and find your test file, setup breakpoint on the first line of your test, Reload the chrome page,  and debug the test to find out the cause

Comment: So I fixed that issue but now my **userService.userDetails** returns null. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: This is a bad idea. Don't add code for testing, that is not needed in your actual application. Please consider testing frameworks like Sinon. They will create mocks, stubs and spies for you!